# Why can't I make a migration using artisan?

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-artisan

When I try to make a migration using

```
PHP artisan make: migration create_packages_table
```

I get this error. What does this mean?:
[image: what does this mean?]

Comment: make composer install

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. Instead post the code/errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Inline image; removed tags from title; trademark capitalization; grammar; layout.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, as [this](https://medium.com/codespace69/php-warning-require-vendor-autoload-php-a8aee073602#:%7E:text=(%2Fvendor%2Fautoload.-,php)%3A%20failed%20to%20open%20stream%3A%20No%20such%20file%20or,in%20%2Flaravel%2Fartisan%20on%20line&text=What%20you%27re%20missing%20is,your%20relative%20path%20is%20correct.) guide said:

> What you’re missing is running composer install, which will import your packages.

Try to do:

```
composer install
```

Or

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your file permissions, in that case specifically in your database directory. From the laravel root directory do this:

```
cd database
ls -l
```

make sure you see the migrations directory and that it's writable for your current user.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: well, all the answers are based on assumptions I guess ;) downvote me and I will delete my answer ;)